# Best way for an AutoResetEvent to Wait only when not Set that number of times

Tags: c#, multithreading, autoresetevent

I'm probably going outside of the proper design for an AutoResetEvent but don't quite know what to turn to.  I want this behavior:

```
var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
autoResetEvent.Set();
autoResetEvent.Set();
autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
// since Set was called twice, I don't want to wait here
autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
```

Unfortunately (for my problem), this is not how an AutoResetEvent behaves.  What is the best class to use for this situation?

Note: I have access to the .NET Parallel Exensions library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to use the Parallel Extensions Library then you should use that instead. It is trivial to invoke worker tasks and then wait on them to finish executing.

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("I'm Awake!");
});

Console.WriteLine("Waiting on task...");

task.Wait();
```

This should produce the following output:

> Waiting on task...
>   I'm Awake!

For more reading on threading in .Net including the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), you should check out this exceptional resource: http://www.albahari.com/threading/